# Regex to remove year from a string PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I have created a database of cigarette and trading cards. Each set title has a year associated with it. For example, `1943` or `2011`. The year is always 4 characters long, but can be anywhere in the string.

Could someone please help me create a regex that will find the year in the string. I tried `'/d{4}\b/'` but it is failing.

Comment: I tried '/d{4}\b/' but it failing for some reaosn

Comment: You forgot a `\ ` in front of the `d`. For the rest the regex should be fine. Thus `'/\d{4}\b/'`

Comment: This is an off-topic typo (duplicate)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(19|20)[0-9][0-9]
```

This will read in only 1900 and 2000 ranged dates.

Comment: Pity your comments are only rude and nonconstructive.

Comment: How so, it picked of 1943 and 2011 when entered on http://regexpal.com/ without fail.  He does not illustrate he wants more than one date, so this will pick the first matching regex 4 character date.

Comment: I can't say I'm sorry enough. I was *wrong*. I had to make a minor edit (added a period) to your question to unlock my downvote and turn it up. Sorry. Apparently I get way more pissed off by bad regex questions than I thought.

Comment: No worries, we're all here to help.

Comment: A little bit shorter one (19|20)\d{2}

Comment: A working example:

`$stringNoYear = preg_match("/(19|20)[0-9][0-9]/",$stringWithYear) ;`

Answer (score 5):

Try this one :

```
/\b\d{4}\b/
```

it will match 4 digits embeded with non-words

Answer (score 1):

`d{4}\b` will match four `d`'s at a word boundary. You forgot the backslash in the character class: should be `\d{4}\b`. Depending on the input data you may also want to consider adding another word boundary (`\b`) at the beginning.

Comment: this extracts 4 numbers together, but maybe also extract 6537 which is not what i want. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full solution:

```
$stringWithYear = '1990 New York Marathon';
$stringNoYear = preg_replace('/(19|20)[0-9][0-9]/', '', $stringWithYear);
echo trim($stringNoYear);  // outputs 'New York Marathon'
```

Answer (score 0):

This too works.. **preg_match("/^1[0-9]{3}$/",$value))**

Checks year of only starting with 1. You could change according to your requirement..