# remove year (yyyy) from string in php

Tags: php, regex

I cant get the regex to identify the date from a string and remove it with string replace:

```
<?php

$string = "keywords=2012+some+words";

echo $string ."<br />";

$new_string = str_replace("keywords=/^([0-9]{4})$/","keywords=",$string);

echo $new_string ;
?>
```

I have read this post [Regex to remove year from a string PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073218/regex-to-remove-year-from-a-string-php)

and just cant get it to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a regex, use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), and pass it an actual regex:

```
$new_string = preg_replace("/^keywords=\d{4}/", "keywords=", $string);
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/dxwxvG